# Apply same field from different records to an operation.

Tags: text-processing, awk

Considering below file:

```
4,5,8,3,41,86,32,
0,0,0,0,38,0,8,8,
9,8,8,9,42,8,9,8,
1,1,7,1,11,2,5,1,
```

How can I compare each $5 with the same field from the next record.

Ex for the first two records:

```
$5(Record one) - $5(Record two) = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following `awk`:

```
awk -F"," 'NR == 1 { x = $5; }; NR != 1 { print x - $5; x = $5; }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplier `awk` solution:

```
awk -F, 'NR!=1 {print x-$5} {x=$5}' file
```